# How to make Thin run on a different port?

Tags: ruby, linux, sinatra, thin

I've a very basic test app. When I execute this command the server ignores the port I specify and runs Thin on port 4567. Why is the port I specify ignored?

```
$ruby xxx.rb start -p 8000

== Sinatra/1.3.3 has taken the stage on 4567 for production with backup from Thin
>> Thin web server (v1.4.1 codename Chromeo)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:4567, CTRL+C to stop
```

xxx.rb file

```
require 'Thin'

rackup_file = "config.ru" 

argv = ARGV
argv << ["-R", rackup_file ] unless ARGV.include?("-R")
argv << ["-e", "production"] unless ARGV.include?("-e")

puts argv.flatten

Thin::Runner.new(argv.flatten).run!
```

config.ru file

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/base'

class SingingRain < Sinatra::Base
    get '/' do
        return 'hello'
    end
end

SingingRain.run!
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your problem is with the line:

```
SingingRain.run!
```

This is Sinatra’s [`run` method](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1343-1345), which tells Sinatra to start its own web server which runs on port 4567 by default. This is in your `config.ru` file, but `config.ru` is just Ruby, so this line is run as if it was in any other `.rb` file. This is why you see Sinatra start up on that port.

When you stop this server with CTRL-C, Thin will try to continue loading the `config.ru` file to determine what app to run. You don’t actually specify an app in your `config.ru`, so you’ll see something like:

```
^C>> Stopping ...

== Sinatra has ended his set (crowd applauds)
/Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:129:in `to_app': missing run or map statement (RuntimeError)
        from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
        ...
```

This error is simply telling you that you didn’t actually specify an app to run in your config file.

Instead of `SingingRain.run!`, use:

```
run SingingRain
```

`run` is a Rack method that specifies which app to run. You could also do `run SingingRain.new` – Sinatra takes steps to enable you to use just the class itself here, or an instance.

The output to this should now just be:

```
>> Thin web server (v1.4.1 codename Chromeo)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:8000, CTRL+C to stop
```

You don’t get the `== Sinatra/1.3.2 has taken the stage on 4567 for production with backup from Thin` message because Sinatra isn’t running its built in server, it’s just your Thin server as you configured it.

Comment: It's really hard sometimes to get good answers like yours. Thank you a world :)

Comment: Your answer worked for me but I have another question. Now when I run the `$ ruby thinx.rb start -d` command I get two `exit` outputs even though the server starts properly. Do you know what's that about?

Comment: @Arman sorry, I don’t know what’s happening with your two outputs – it doesn’t happen for me.

Answer (score 16):

```
#\ -p 8000
```

put this at the top of the config.ru

Comment: This worked for Sinatra/Thin by running command "rackup." Perfect!

Answer (score -3):

in your config.ru add

> set :port=> 8000

Also i would highly suggest using Sinatra with something like passenger+nginx which makes deploying to production a breeze. But You need not worry about this if you are going to deploy to heroku.

Comment: Doesn't Thin:Runner constructor specifically parse command line arguments as documented here? https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/blob/master/lib/thin/runner.rb

Comment: that looks like it but iam not really sure how that works out when u are using a config.ru file. If you had not created a config.ru file and it was just .rb thin does accept the -p parameter